# prevent a runtime error when filtering an array that might not exist at certainty point?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this reducer state chunk, that is causing a runtime error
(TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value) is not iterable)
since, at a certain point, the object might not be available in the state, any idea how to prevent the run time from stumbling on the part of chunk that is not available (childGroup) at the current moment? and run it only when certain criteria are met I tried adding ?? [] before the filter but typescript errored out cannot call filter on never. the issue happens when I want to delete the parent group only when there is no child group! , if there is a child group works like charm.

```js
// REMOVE  GROUP
    case types.DELETE__GROUP:

      return {
        ...state,
        parentGroup: {
          ...state.parentGroup,
          [action.payload.parentId!]: state.parentGrou[action.payload.parentId!]?.filter((el) => el.id !== action.payload.id),
        },
        childGroup: {
          ...state.childGroup,
          [action.payload.parentId!]: [...state.childGroup[action.payload.parentId!]?.filter((el) => el.parentId !== action.payload.id)],
        },
      };
```

Comment: You have many things wrong in there, starting by assignment to a spreading object, that would never work.

Comment: Can you share the rest of the code please?

Answer (score 1):

Conditional indexed access is spelled `?.[]` in both TypeScript and JavaScript.  So in addition to the `?.filter` you need to add `?.` to your `[action.payload.parentId!]` index, making that entire line:

```js
[action.payload.parentId!]:
  [
    ...state.childGroup?.[action.payload.parentId!]?.filter((el) => el.parentId !== action.payload.id)
  ],
```

But consider in investing in some utilities around this to make it clearer what the actual business logic is (for example [`Immer.js`](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/example-setstate))

Comment: not working for some reason

Comment: What's the error you see?

Comment: white screen... the logic is not kicking for some reason